# React js props undefined when passing state to another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I am trying to pass the toggleState value from my Sidebar.jsx as props to another file Screens.jsx, which toggles between displaying the homepage or displaying nothing based on the toggleState value. However, when I try to access the value of the props in Screens.jsx, it tells me the value is undefined.

Sidebar.jsx

```
import Screens from './Screens';
import {useState} from 'react';

function Sidebar() {
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleState(1)}
      >
      </div>

      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleState(2)}
      >
      </div>

      <Screens toggleState={toggleState} />

    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Screens.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Homepage from './homepage';

function Screens({toggleState}) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(1);

  console.log(toggleState);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(toggleState);
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 752 }}>
      { isActive === 1 ? <Homepage /> : null }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Screens;
```

Both Sidebar and Screens are imported in my Home.jsx. I'm not sure if this might be causing the issue.

Home.jsx

```
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar';
import Screens from '../components/screens';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: 1200, height: 792 }}>

        <div style={{ width: 71, height: 792, marginTop: -42, marginLeft: -10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <Sidebar />
        </div>

        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 670, height: 752, backgroundColor: '#1e203c' }}>
          <Screens />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: there is no problem in the code that your provide, maybe is something that you did not put in your question

Comment: @andresmartinez I edited my question to say that I'm importing both my Sidebar and Screens in my Home.jsx. Do you think this could be causing the issue?

Comment: Now I see what your problem is, but you can't tell to Sidebar that change something it can't reach. I'll explain you what I think you want to do.

Comment: Why `Screens` is rendering in two places, Home and Sidebar both?

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook is missing a dependency array to update the local state

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsActive(toggleState);
}, [setIsActive, toggleState]);
```

But this is an anti-pattern in React, just consume the `toggleState` prop directly in the component.

```
function Screens({ toggleState }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 752 }}>
      {toggleState === 1 && <Homepage />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You are rendering the `Screens` component in two places, once by the `Sidebar` component and once again in the `Home` component. [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the common parent component `Home` and pass down all the required props.

Example:

```
function Home() {
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: 1200, height: 792 }}>
        <div style={{ width: 71, height: 792, marginTop: -42, marginLeft: -10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <Sidebar {...{ setToggleState, toggleState }} />
        </div>

        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 670, height: 752, backgroundColor: '#1e203c' }}>
          <Screens {...{ toggleState }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Sidebar` is passed both the `setToggleState` callback to attach to the `div` elements onClick`handler, and`toggleState`is passed along to`Screens`.

```
function Sidebar({ toggleState, setToggleState }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setToggleState(1)}>
      </div>

      <div onClick={() => setToggleState(2)}>
      </div>

      <Screens toggleState={toggleState} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Screens` receives the `toggleState` prop as before.

```
function Screens({ toggleState }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 752 }}>
      {toggleState === 1 && <Homepage />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-js-props-undefined-when-passing-state-to-another-file]

Comment: I tried this and get the error Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. And the console.log still shows undefined for toggleState. However, it prints out the correct toggleState value before the undefined, meaning the toggleState value suddenly becomes undefined for some reason.

Comment: @MagnusTan It seems you are rendering the `Screens` component in several places around the app. Lift the state up to a common ancestor component and pass the state and state updater function down as props. I've updated my answer with also with explanation and example.

Comment: Somehow, the Screens.jsx still doesn't toggle the homepage on and off even though it is receiving the correct toggleState. It seems like Screens isn't reacting at all to the code since I turned it off manually in the Screens.jsx but it still shows the homepage. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @MagnusTan Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-props-undefined-when-passing-state-to-another-file-dgzjrm) demo. I've also linked it in my answer.

Comment: Strange. Mine is like your running example but the Screens can't seem to toggle on and off. There might be something else that's causing the problem. I'll try to restart react and rewrite and clean up some of my code to see if that helps. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @MagnusTan Yeah, killing any hot reloaders/code watchers and restarting the development server sometimes resolves issues where the server is running your latest code changes.

Answer (score 1):

use the state from your Home file:

```
import Sidebar from '../components/SideBar';
import Screens from '../components/Screens';

function Home() {

const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: 1200, height: 792 }}>

        <div style={{ width: 71, height: 792, marginTop: -42, marginLeft: -10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <SideBar setToggleState={setToggleState} />
        </div>

        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 670, height: 752, backgroundColor: '#1e203c' }}>
          <Screens toggleState={toggleState} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

use the setState from the SideBar file to change the state and remove de Screens import:

```
function Sidebar({setToggleState}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleState(1)}
      >
        one
      </div>

      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleState(2)}
      >
       two
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

is not nessesary use other state in Screen file:

```
import App from './App';

function Screens({toggleState}) {

  console.log(toggleState);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 752 }}>
      { toggleState === 1 ? <App /> : null }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Screens;
```

but if you wat to use it, you have to say to your useEffect that the variable change:

```
...
useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(toggleState);
  },[toggleState]);
...
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and the toggleState is no longer undefined but the Screens.jsx doesn't toggle the homepage on and off when I switch between toggleState in the Sidebar.  How do I get the Screens to update everytime I change the toggleState in the Sidebar? useEffect doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Somehow, the Screens.jsx still doesn't toggle the homepage on and off even though it is receiving the correct toggleState. It seems like Screens isn't reacting at all to the code since I turned it off manually in the Screens.jsx but it still shows the homepage. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @MagnusTan maybe you have something more that we can see in your question :C

Comment: I'm not sure. All the relevant stuff should be there now. I'll try to redo some of it and clean up the code to see if that helps. Thanks for the help anyway.